# difficulty matching single letter programming languages with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse through some text searching for different programming language names such as python, java, etc. with regular expressions. Unfortunately, regex is not something I am wholly comfortable with but finding the desired matches for languages with multiple letters was pretty easy. However, when trying to match single letter languages I am having some difficulties. For example, here is my pattern for the C language:

`'\Wc[^\+#\w](\W|$)|\Wc$'`

this works great except that it also matches for objective-c. Is there a way to write a pattern that does not match if 'c' is preceded by 'objective-'? I am also writing my program in python so if there is a better approach i'd be grateful if someone pointed that out.

examples of strings that should not match but do:

`objective-d – alternative or supplement to objective-c`

`compile clojure to objective-c`

it matches for every other situation I have tested except when objective-c is present in the string

Comment: can you provide some more pattern of your "language names" ?

Comment: You need to provide an example string where your regex is supposed to work, but it doesn't

Comment: @Tarzan I am not exactly sure what you are asking but for every other pattern I use to match a language all I needed to do was surround the language name with '\W' like '\Wjava\W'

Comment: @Bryan It is important to understand what this does. \W will match any single non-alphabet, non-numberic character.

Comment: @Chirag64 I understand what is the intended use of '\W'. many of the string contain multiple langues in a sequence like java/c++/c which I also need to match. Hence the use of '\W'

Comment: You can use "[^(objective\-)]C" (without quotes) to match any string that starts with C but does not precede with 'objective-'. But I'm still not sure what kind of instances will 'C' come in. I could help you if you could provide me with more string examples that you're processing.

Comment: @Chirag64 Sorry for the confusion. here is an example of a string that properly matches with c: `a good tutorial about pointers in c` or `ada, c, rem and mod. what the what? `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.compile(r'(?<!objective-)\bc\b',re.I)
```

This expression doesn't match:

```
objective-d – alternative or supplement to objective-c
compile clojure to objective-c
```

and does match:

```
compile with c
c expression
compile c program
contains a c struct
strict C syntax
```

The `(?<!...)` is a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html), meaning that the assertion is not a part of the match but requires that the match not be preceded by that expression.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have a list that contains all language names.

Is this what you want?

```
>>> txt = "objective-d – alternative or supplement to objective-c but not c or java,python"
>>> lang_names.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
>>> lang_names
['objective-c', 'python', 'c']
>>> regexp = re.compile("(?:^|\W)(" + "|".join(lang_names) + ")(?:\W|$)")
>>> matches = regexp.finditer(txt)
>>> for m in matches:
...     print m.group(1)
...     
objective-c
c
python
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by mojo and M42, use negative lookbehind.

Here's the updated regex:

```
(?<!objective-)(c)\W
```

and an updated example on regex101

http://regex101.com/r/zV6aR3

<s>[^(objective)]\W(c)\W</s>

Here's the implementation on regex101.com with your example strings:

http://regex101.com/r/zS3uK6

Comment: What do you think `[^(objective)]` matches?

Comment: It does not match the string if it has a non-alphabet, non-numberic character with a C preceded by the word 'objective'. So it won't match objective-C.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong. `[^(objective)]` matches one character that is not `(` or `o` or `b` ... `)`.

Comment: @M42 You're right. I just tested it. Is there any way to implement what I was trying to achieve here?

Comment: Use a negative look behind. See @mojo 's answer.